# How to delete an sqlite/websql database from ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sqlite, ngcordova

Good day

Am currently working with ionic 1 and angularjs 1. I am trying to add a function to store data locally using ngcordova SQLite plugin and have run into a little bit of a problem. Since I have changed my database structure in my code I am unable to create new tables even after dropping my previous tables in my code. I have removed the application from my phone and deleted the WEBSQL data from my browser several times and still it looks for table fields which I have removed previous.

Console Error:

> ERROR: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: User)

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Base on a few tests I did yesterday I have found out that my main issue was incorrect code blocks so I kept getting empty tables or none at all. Secondly it seems as if WebSql is hard to remove so you might have to rename your database to get ride of it. In terms of the db on your phone you can delete it using:

> db = window.sqlitePlugin.deleteDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'}, successcb, errorcb);

If you wrap this into a function you can use it during testing to delete your db if any problems occur. I hope this helps out anyone having a similar error.